# How to fix MacBook Pro rebooting every 3 minutes due to missing dfrd checkins

Tags: macbook, touchpad, macbook-pro, kernel-panic

The MacBook Pro of a friend reboots every 3 minutes after it's turned on. It shows the following message after rebooting:

```
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xfffffff00e688560): userspace watchdog timeout: no successful checkins from dfrd in 180 seconds
dfrd has not exited since first loaded
service: dfrd, total successful checkins in 299 seconds: 11, last successful checkin: 180 seconds ago
service: remoted, total successful checkins in 290 seconds: 29, last successful checkin: 0 seconds ago
service: bridgeaudiod, total successful checkins in 299 seconds: 30, last successful checkin: 0 seconds ago
service: logd, total successful checkins in 299 seconds: 29, last successful checkin: 0 seconds ago

Debugger message: panic
Memory ID: 0x6
OS release type: User
OS version: 20P5060
macOS version: 21G651
Kernel version: Darwin Kernel Version 22.5.0: Thu Jun  8 17:10:34 PDT 2023; root:xnu-8796.121.3~5/RELEASE_ARM64_T8010
KernelCache UUID: 529696CF800037812B4D1FDE991978DD
Kernel UUID: 59AAE2A2-9BC4-3D6A-8F6B-DFBC7B9815ED
Boot session UUID: 450641F2-9D3D-43C5-9633-A3F34B8726A4
iBoot version: iBoot-8422.121.2
secure boot?: YES
roots installed: 0
x86 EFI Boot State: 0x16
x86 System State: 0x0
x86 Power State: 0x0
x86 Shutdown Cause: 0xec
x86 Previous Power Transitions: 0x70707060400
PCIeUp link state: 0x1614
macOS kernel slide: not available
Paniclog version: 14
Kernel slide:      0x0000000008028000
Kernel text base:  0xfffffff00f02c000
mach_absolute_time: 0x1ac57928f
Epoch Time:        sec       usec
  Boot    : 0x65eb1e84 0x0006aa01
  Sleep   : 0x00000000 0x00000000
  Wake    : 0x00000000 0x00000000
  Calendar: 0x65eb1fab 0x0008ce79

Zone info:
  Zone map: 0xffffffdc26248000 - 0xffffffe226248000
  . VM    : 0xffffffdc26248000 - 0xffffffdd0c8ac000
  . RO    : 0xffffffdd0c8ac000 - 0xffffffdd59578000
  . GEN0  : 0xffffffdd59578000 - 0xffffffde3fbdc000
  . GEN1  : 0xffffffde3fbdc000 - 0xffffffdf26240000
  . GEN2  : 0xffffffdf26240000 - 0xffffffe00c8a8000
  . GEN3  : 0xffffffe00c8a8000 - 0xffffffe0f2f10000
  . DATA  : 0xffffffe0f2f10000 - 0xffffffe226248000
  Metadata: 0xffffffeac4de4000 - 0xffffffeac65e4000
  Bitmaps : 0xffffffeac65e4000 - 0xffffffeac6714000
  Extra   : 0 - 0

TPIDRx_ELy = {1: 0xffffffdd596642f8  0: 0x0000000000000000  0ro: 0x000000016f7130e0 }
CORE 0 is the one that panicked. Check the full backtrace for details.
CORE 1: PC=0x00000001934cb2c4, LR=0x00000001935549f4, FP=0x000000016d67e500
Compressor Info: 0% of compressed pages limit (OK) and 0% of segments limit (OK) with 0 swapfiles and OK swap space
Total cpu_usage: 14310736
Thread task pri cpu_usage
0xffffffdd596642f8 watchdogd 97 0
0xffffffdd5a03eba8 launchd 37 0
0xffffffdd59652ba8 kernel_task 0 4028243
0xffffffdd59a7c2f8 kernel_task 0 4030123

Panicked task 0xffffffde3f3b6d00: 173 pages, 3 threads: pid 38: watchdogd
Panicked thread: 0xffffffdd596642f8, backtrace: 0xffffffec7eee71a0, tid: 912
          lr: 0xfffffff00f21d868  fp: 0xffffffec7eee7210
          lr: 0xfffffff00f33e014  fp: 0xffffffec7eee7280
          lr: 0xfffffff00f33cfd4  fp: 0xffffffec7eee7360
          lr: 0xfffffff00f1e15fc  fp: 0xffffffec7eee7370
          lr: 0xfffffff00f21d2a4  fp: 0xffffffec7eee7720
          lr: 0xfffffff00f86d03c  fp: 0xffffffec7eee7740
          lr: 0xfffffff00e688560  fp: 0xffffffec7eee7760
          lr: 0xfffffff00e687eec  fp: 0xffffffec7eee7780
          lr: 0xfffffff00e6870b8  fp: 0xffffffec7eee78a0
          lr: 0xfffffff00f7fd8e4  fp: 0xffffffec7eee7a40
          lr: 0xfffffff00f30d84c  fp: 0xffffffec7eee7b60
          lr: 0xfffffff00f222d5c  fp: 0xffffffec7eee7be0
          lr: 0xfffffff00f1fc830  fp: 0xffffffec7eee7c40
          lr: 0xfffffff00f210a38  fp: 0xffffffec7eee7d80
          lr: 0xfffffff00f334114  fp: 0xffffffec7eee7e30
          lr: 0xfffffff00f33d3f4  fp: 0xffffffec7eee7f10
          lr: 0xfffffff00f1e15fc  fp: 0xffffffec7eee7f20
```

The problem has been going on for a few days, he has no idea what could have caused it.
There are no external devices connected to the MacBook. I tried to install the latest updates, but that takes too long, so the reboot occurs before the update can finish. I also booted in recovery mode and tried reinstalling macOS, but before it can finish, the reboot occurs.
Approximately one year ago I replaced the trackpad of the MacBook Pro. It worked fine for a year and it's still working fine.

The touchbar (the black long element at the top of the keyboard) remains blank, maybe it's defect. I also read, that `dfrd`, as it says in the dump message, has something to do with the `TouchBarServer`. I tried if I could fix it by killing the `TouchBarServer` (so that it reboots) every 3 minutes as described [in this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/440480/monterey-repeated-kernel-panics-watchdog-timeout-no-successful-checkins-fro), but that didn't prevent the reboot.

The builtin tool to check the disk health (which runs less than 3 minutes fortunately) doesn't find any problems with the SSD.

EDIT: I replaced the touchbar, now the MacBook is working fine again without reboots.

Comment: Can you test the SSD?  It may have a hardware issue.

Comment: The builtin tool to check the disk health doesn't find any problems with the SSD.

Comment: If a full install does not work because of a reboot then there may be another hardware error

Comment: I suppose it is possible that something bashed the disk preventing proper operation or installation. You may need to take it to Apple Service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced the touchbar, now the MacBook is working fine again without reboots.